# Prismic asHtml() escapes HTML for rich text field in Astro

Tags: javascript, html, richtext, prismic.io, astrojs

I am attempting to use Astro for the first time, and I am also attempting to use Prismic as the data source. In my Prismic project, I have a number of [rich text](https://prismic.io/docs/core-concepts/rich-text-title) fields, and I simply want to render them as HTML in my Astro component. Per the Prismic docs, I need to render them using [asHTML](https://prismic.io/docs/core-concepts/rich-text-title), which is part of [@prismicio/helpers](https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/prismic-helpers-v2-migration-guide).

In my use case, I have, as an example, a `header_text` and a `test_item_1` field in prismic. Using this code below, I am able to fetch the data and store it in a couple variables.

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import * as prismicH from '@prismicio/helpers';

import {getFrontPage} from '../prismic.js';

const fp = await getFrontPage();
const {data} = fp.results[0];

const headerText = prismicH.asHTML(data.header_text);
const textItem1 = prismicH.asHTML(data.text_item_1);
```

When I use the [`<Debug>`](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/troubleshooting/#astro-debug--component) component to show me `data`, I get this:

```
{
  "header_text": [
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "text": "We have met the needs of Manufacturers, Fabricators,\nInstallers, Inventors, and Machine Shops for over 22 Years.\nIn Oregon and across the United States.",
      "spans": []
    }
  ],
  "text_item_1": [
    {
      "type": "heading3",
      "text": "Our Clients",
      "spans": [
        {
          "start": 0,
          "end": 11,
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "text": "We  work with Manufacturers, Fabricators, Installers, Inventors, and  Machine Shops who need a better laser mark, shorter lead times, and  cost-effective pricing.",
      "spans": []
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "text": " ",
      "spans": []
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "text": "For these organizations, we are  a reasonably priced, efficient, and high-quality operation that can  guarantee an exceptional mark on various products and material types.",
      "spans": []
    }
  ],
}
```

which is what I should be passing to `asHTML()` per the [docs](https://prismic.io/docs/technical-reference/prismicio-helpers#ashtmlfield-linkresolver-htmlserializer).

However, when I display the HTML in the template

```
{headerText}

{textItem1)
```

I get the escaped HTML, instead of the rendered HTML

```
<p>We have met the needs of Manufacturers, Fabricators,<br />Installers, Inventors, and Machine Shops for over 22 Years.<br />In Oregon and across the United States.</p> 

<h3><strong>Our Clients</strong></h3><p>We work with Manufacturers, Fabricators, Installers, Inventors, and Machine Shops who need a better laser mark, shorter lead times, and cost-effective pricing.</p><p> </p><p>For these organizations, we are a reasonably priced, efficient, and high-quality operation that can guarantee an exceptional mark on various products and material types.</p>
```

So as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly. Why is my HTML being escaped? I don't have any links in my text, so I don't need a linkResolver or HTML serializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue wasn't with Prismic, but Astro. Astro has the [set:html](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) template directive, which is responsible for displaying the unescaped HTMl (similar to [v-html](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) in Vue).

In my template, all I had to do was

```
<div set:html={headerText}></div>
```

and it displays the HTML as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you want to have the HTML without any additional wrapper element, you can use:

```html
<Fragment set:html={yourVariable} />
```

https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#fragments--multiple-elements